# Wrap up multiple <td>'s together on mobile with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-tables

**Target**
I've a horizontal table. I created a desktop view and a mobile view. In the mobile view, all informations are displayed under eatch other while on desktop, every information is displayed beside each other.
This is how it should look like:
*Desktop*
[image: Desktop]
*Mobile*
[image: Mobile]

**My current state**
I work with Bootstrap. I made a table layout and it looks how it should on desktop. If I resize it to mobile, the informations won't wrap up underneath each other but stay horizontal like in the desktop view:
[image: Reality]

[Codepen-Demo of current solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzoNOk)
And the Code from Codepen (note, I use Bootstrap, so I don't think the SO-generated view is suitable):
*HTML*

```
<table class="table table-striped borderless">
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">06:33</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1 circle-td">
        <span class="circle"><p>2h 55'</p></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3"><strong>Drive</strong></td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">18922</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">Home - Stop</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">06:33</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1 circle-td">
        <span class="circle"><p>2h 55'</p></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">
        <small>Inbetween</small><br />
        <strong>Snack</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">18922</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">Stop</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">06:33</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1 circle-td">
        <span class="circle"><p>2h 55'</p></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3"><strong>Drive</strong></td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">18922</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">Stop - End</td>
</tr>
```

*CSS*

```
.table.borderless>tbody>tr>td{
    border-top: none;
}
.circle-td{
    background: #fff;   
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #353535, transparent);
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 1px auto;    
    text-align: center;
}

.circle{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 12px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background: white;
}
.circle p{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**What I've tried**
I tried multiple ugly things:

- Create another table inside of the *content-TD*.
  Result: the whole layout is messed up
- Made everything with div's instead of a fixed table.
  Result: The layout-switch worked, but the circle & line didn't worked anymore. And I think, the table layout is better maintainable.
- Searched for wrapping table-cells with Bootstrap, but found only word-wrapping and not whole `<td>`'s.

**Question**
Can you help me to reach my target in order to wrap up all `<td>`'s underneath each other? I'm out of ideas.
You can also show me other ways for the solution, I only have those limitations:
It must be done with Bootstrap or at least work with bootstrap.
The layout must be like displayed in the *Target*-section. I can't change something about this layout.

I can use CSS3 and I would be happy if it would work without JavaScript; but if only possible with, I also can include JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it is not the best solution of the problem, but in my opinion it will solve it with least possible changes in your code and just utilizing Bootstrap's classes.

```css
.table.borderless>tbody>tr>td{
  border-top: none;
}
.circle-td{
  background: #fff;   
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #353535, transparent);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 1px auto;    
  text-align: center;
}

.circle{
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 12px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background: white;
}
.circle p{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped borderless">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">06:33</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1 circle-td">
      <span class="circle"><p>2h 55'</p></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <strong>Drive</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">18922</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">Home - Stop</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">06:33</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1 circle-td">
      <span class="circle"><p>2h 55'</p></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <small>Inbetween</small><br />
        <strong>Snack</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">18922</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">Stop</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">06:33</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1 circle-td">
      <span class="circle"><p>2h 55'</p></span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <strong>Drive</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">18922</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">HStop - End</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```